# How do I combine onclick and onkeypress events for one button in HTML?

Tags: html

So I am making a simple calculator app. Now I have a button to input '1' in the calculator. What I want is whenever I click on '1' button or press '1' on my keyboard, 1 should be input into the calculator. Here is my code -

```
<td><input type="button" class="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 49){calculator.display.value += '1'}"></td>
```

And my calculator display box is -

```
<input type="text" name="display" id="display" disabled>
```

Now what happens is when I click '1' button, 1 is displayed in my display box. But when I press '1' on my keyboard, nothing happens. 
But when I click '1' button first, then press '1' on my keyboard, '11' gets into the display box, that is, the input is accepted through the keyboard.
I want this input via keyboard without having to click the button. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you shouldn't be using inline js - it's bad practice that leads to hard to maintain code

Comment: When you click on button, focus is not anymore on text field. After clicking of button, set focus on text field.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric how do I set the focus on a button on key press? Like when I press '1' on my keyboard, the focus should automatically be on button '1'. how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply the `onkeypress` event to a specific element, it won't act the way you want it to because the element must be focused in order to catch the key press event, because the event is relative to that element.

```js
let display = document.getElementById("display");
document.body.onkeypress = function() {
  // Include all numbers, 0-10
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (event.keyCode == i + 48) display.value += i;
  }
};
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="display" disabled />
  <br>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="display.value += '1'">1</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="display.value += '2'">2</button>
  <button id="btn3" onclick="display.value += '3'">3</button>
</body>

</html>
```

---

And on another note, somehow unrelated to the question but has been brought up here, regarding *inline JS* - it is generally considered bad practice. Some cases might justify it, but it is general consensus that it should be avoided. **Read more:**

- [Is inline JavaScript good or bad?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61731/is-inline-javascript-good-or-bad/61741)
- [Why Inline CSS And JavaScript Code Is Such A Bad Thing](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)
- [Reddit - why is inline onclick="function()" considered such a bad practice?](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3kamqn/why_is_inline_onclickfunction_considered_such_a/)

Comment: do I write the first snippet into a script tag?

Comment: @VipulModak You can, and you should do so either in a seperate `file.js` or just in a floating script tag in the end of your body (depends on what this project is for). The example above does use inline js to match what you did but it is considered *bad practice*. I've already edited my question to mention that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This project is for learning so it's fine. Will use external js for further projects. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the position of your `onkeypress()`, if you move that out of the input tag for example in the `<body>` or in your `<table>` you could have a bigger "focus zone" where the event could be caught:

```html
<head>
  <script>
  function onClick(val)
  {
    document.getElementById("display").value += val;
  }
    
  function onPress()
  {
    switch(event.keyCode)
      {
        case 49: document.getElementById("display").value += 1;
        break;
        case 50: document.getElementById("display").value += 2;
        break;
      }
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body onkeypress="onPress()">

  <table>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="onClick(1)">
    </td>
  </table>
  
  <input type="text" name="display" id="display" disabled/>
  
</body>
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

`onkeypress` works only if the focus is on the button. If you don't click the button first, the focus isn't on the button and the button can't recognize the keypress. As soon as you click the button, it gets the focus and it can recognize the keypress.
You could try adding the onkeypress event to your body tag.

```
<body onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 49){calculator.display.value += '1'}">
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Since I am making a calculator, I must add all the keys of my keyboard to the body. So when I add onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 49){calculator.display.value += '1'}" and onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 50){calculator.display.value += '2'}". When I press '1' or '2' on keyboard, input into text box is always '1'.

Comment: You're right, sorry. If you really want to do inline JS, you could do if(event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57){calculator.display.value += (event.KeyCode - 48).toString()} But I recommend to create either an separate file or a script tag in your body. For both ways you should take the Answer of NonameSL as reference

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer onkeypress will only work if the element is focused. Also you should no use inline JS but let both event refer to a function which you execute when the event occurs. Here is an example with an input element.

```js
function myFunc () {
 alert("event happening");
}
```

```css
input:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input onkeypress="myFunc()" onclick="myFunc()"/>
```

When the element is clicked the event fires. Also when the element is focused and a key is pressed the event fires. Hopefully this is helpful.